# Is it possible to align several single-line text frames to the common baseline?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, alignment

Imagine I have two or three text frames each containing a single line of text. They sit next to each other, at a distance. I wish to align them "between themselves" so that they all appear to be typed as one line of text (of different fonts and sizes) even if they in reality are not. Can I do this or not?

P.S. I'm not using the document-wide grid (or whatever this is appropriately called). I just wish to select all three frames, apply some inter-aligning command and be done with it. Ideally one frame should be selectable as a reference, and the two others should be moved to match that reference baseline position.

Answer (score 1):

Use the text frame options to vertically align the text within the frame.

I set the vertical justification to bottom, but you could use a fixed first baseline offset instead (found in the "Baseline Options" tab of the same dialog).

[image]

You can then use the regular align tools to align the frames:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy - 2 steps: Set each the text for each object to align to baseline grid and then align the objects to each other using one of them as a key object.

1. Select them all, choose type tool to give you access to type controls, in Para Attributes in control panel > Align to baseline grid.
2. Selection tool click on the "key object" while they are all selected and that will display a heavier guide color and set alignment to bottom - the frames will all move so the bottom edges (and baselines) line up with the key object.